# ¿Cómo cerrar los componentes hijos menos el que ha sido clickeado en vue 3?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue3

Estoy haciendo una sidebar que contiene varios menús desplegables. Todo funciona, pero no sé cómo lograr que al clickear uno de los submenús los demás se cierren. Ejemplo: si cliqueo el submenú 1 y tengo abierto el 2, se cierre éste dejando solo el 1 abierto.

La estructura es la siguiente: un componente padre sidebar en el cual tengo llamados 4 componentes hijos dropdown los cuales reciben determinadas propiedades como título, ícono, opciones del menú, etc.

Componente padre:

```
    <script setup>
      import { ref } from 'vue';
      import SidebarDropdown from '../DropDown.vue';

      const is_spanded = ref(false);
      const toggleMenu = () => is_spanded.value = !is_spanded.value ;
      const spandDropdown = () => { 
        if(is_spanded.value == false) toggleMenu();
      }
    </script>

    <template>
      <aside class="bg-primary" :class="{ is_spanded:is_spanded }">
        <!-- logotype -->
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="@/assets/imgs/minilog.png" alt="SGTI_LOGO">
        </div>
        <!-- Toggle button -->
        <button 
          id="toggle-wrap"
          class="absolute w-6 h-6 -right-2 top-20 z-100 shadow-md bg-secondary rounded-full material-symbols-outlined text-[18px] text-third transition duration-700 ease-out hover:-translate-x-1"
          @click="toggleMenu">
          chevron_right
        </button>
        <!--menu options-->
        <div class="menu">
          <h3 class="hidden lg:block font-bold uppercase ml-4 text-third">
            General.
          </h3>
          <SidebarDropdown title="Tickets" icon="local_activity" :options="[]" toggle="false" @in-focus="spandDropdown"/>
          <SidebarDropdown title="Correo" icon="mail" :options="[]" toggle="false" @in-focus="spandDropdown"/>
          <SidebarDropdown title="Chat" icon="chat" :options="[]" toggle="false" @in-focus="spandDropdown"/>
          <SidebarDropdown title="Gestion" icon="manage_accounts" :options="[]" toggle="false" @in-focus="spandDropdown"/>
        </div>
        <!--user config-->
        <div class="flex mt-auto user-card p-2 rounded">
          <span class="user-card-text order-2">Cliente</span>
          <button class="material-symbols-sharp ml-auto logout-icon order-1 text-third">logout</button>
        </div>

      </aside>
    </template>
```

```
    <style lang="scss">
    aside{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: calc(2rem + 32px);
      padding: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      
      transition: 0.3s ease-out;
      
      @media (max-width: 768px){
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
        min-height: 100vh;
      }

      h3, .menu-item .menu-text,.desplegable-icon {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: -999;
        transition: 0.2s ease-out;
        cursor: auto;
      }

      .menu {
        margin: 0 -1rem;
        @apply mt-20;

        
        .menu-item {
          @apply flex items-center relative;
          padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
          transition: 0.2s ease-out;
          &:hover {
            @apply bg-secondary
          }
        }
        .material-symbols-sharp { 
          @apply text-[2.5rem] text-third;
          transition: 0.2s ease-out;
        }
        .menu-text {
          @apply text-third ml-3;
          transition: 0.2s ease-out;
        }

        /*stylos para el submenu cuando la barra no esta desplegada*/
        .menu-list {
          display : none ;
          // @apply bg-secondary absolute left-full -mt-14 p-5 min-w-[200px] text-third;
        }
      }

      &.is_spanded {
        width: var(--sidebar-width);

        #toggle-wrap {
          transform: rotate(-180deg);
        }
        h3, .menu-item .menu-text,.desplegable-icon {
          opacity: 1;
          z-index: 999;
        }
        .material-symbols-sharp { 
          @apply text-[2rem];
        }
        .logout-icon { 
          @apply order-2 text-secondary;
        }
        .user-card{
          @apply bg-third;
        }
        .user-card-text {
          visibility: visible;
        }
        .menu-list {
          display: block;
           @apply text-third left-0 mt-0;
           li{
            @apply ml-5 mt-3
           }
        }
      }

      .logout-icon{
        &:hover {
          @apply text-secondary
        }
      }
      .user-card-text {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }

    </style>
```

y este seria mi componente hijo:

```
    <script setup>
        import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
        const props = defineProps({
            icon: String,
            title: String,
            options: Array,
            toggle: Boolean
        });
        const emit = defineEmits(['inFocus']);

        const list_is_spanded = ref(false);
        const toggleList = () => list_is_spanded.value = !list_is_spanded.value;
        onMounted(()=> console.log(props));
    </script>

    <template>
      <div @click="emit('inFocus')" :class="[list_is_spanded ? 'bg-secondary': 'bg-primary']">
        <div class="menu-item cursor-pointer" @click="toggleList" >
          <span class="material-symbols-sharp">{{ props.icon }}</span>
          <span class="menu-text">{{ props.title }}</span>
          <span class="ml-auto material-symbols-outlined desplegable-icon text-third">chevron_right</span>
        </div>
        <ol class="menu-list" v-show="list_is_spanded">
          <li>opcion1</li>
          <li>opcion2</li>
          <li>opcion3</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </template>

    <style scoped lang="scss">

    </style>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero evitar es ese efecto donde todas las barras están desplegadas.

Comment: No estas usando ningun store??? entonces, vas a tener que hacer un poco de magia... Si tenes un store (como pinia) es algo mucho mas sencillo, porque el estado del menu lo guardas alli...

Comment: sin store, cada hijo, va a tener que avisarle a papa que cambio su estado, y papa va a tener que decirle al resto de los hijos que se cierren....

Comment: si eso estaba pensando en usar un store,

Comment: Proba con un store... usa un array de boleanos para solo prender uno y apagar el resto... que cada hijo busque en el store su value... cuando uno se abre, primero cerras todos y luego abris el que queres... probalo, y si tenes otra duda volve...